# Copying a file that doesn't have a file extension in batch

Tags: batch-file

Here is the code, it says can't find defined file:

```
copy /y "%windir%/System32/drivers/etc/hosts" "%cd%/hosts/backup/hosts"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using normal slashes instead of backslashes.
Try the following code:

```
copy /y "%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" "%cd%\hosts\backup\hosts"
```